# JEST: Test case inside a function not getting values from the constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I tried writing test cases wrapped inside a class so that calling  a method will execute the test case. But the url value will be initialized inside the beforeAll/ beforeEach block due to dependency factor. In that case i am not getting the url value, which results the failure of the test case execution.I could not pass url as an argument as well(url will only be initialized in beforeAll block). Is there any alternative soultion available to overcome this issue?

sampleTest.ts

```
export interface TestCaseArgumentsType {
  baseUrl: string;
  url: string;
}
export class Sample {
  set args(value: TestCaseArgumentsType) {
    this.arguments = value;
  }
  private arguments!: TestCaseArgumentsType;
  sampleTestFunction() {
    console.log(this.arguments.url); // **expected**: sampleUrl **actual**: cannot set property url of undefined

    it('to check the before each execution effects in the test case', () => {
      console.log(this.arguments.url); // sampleUrl
    });
  }
}
```

sampleTestSuite.test.ts

```
import { Sample, TestCaseArgumentsType } from './sampleTest';

describe('User Route', () => {
  let sample = new Sample();
  // Test suite
  describe('GET Request', () => {
    // Preparing Test Suite
    beforeAll(async () => {
      sample.args = <TestCaseArgumentsType>{ url: `sampleUrl` };
    }, 20000);
    // Executing
    sample.sampleTestFunction();
  });
});
```

Comment: I executed your code and it works fine.

Comment: @slideshowp2  did you get the url inside test case? I had got an error.

Comment: I got `sampleUrl` for `console.log(this.arguments.url)` and the test passes

Comment: how did you run this code. by installing jest?

Comment: With `test-jest` and `jest`

Comment: yes, I have tried the same way. it works fine for this sample code. But in my case i have db operations inside beforeAll and test case as well. will that be problem?

Comment: @slideshowp2 i had edited the code. could you please try in this code.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the execution order of the code.

The key point is `beforeAll` function is executed before calling `it`, not before calling `sample.sampleTestFunction()`. So, when you call `sample.sampleTestFunction()` method, the statement `sample.args = <TestCaseArgumentsType>{ url: 'sampleUrl' }` inside the `beforeAll` function will not execute. The `arguments` property of `sample` is `undefined`. That's why you got error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

When `jestjs` test runner prepare to calling `it`, then, test runner will call `beforeAll` function firstly

`sampleTest.ts`:

```js
export interface TestCaseArgumentsType {
  baseUrl: string;
  url: string;
}
export class Sample {
  set args(value: TestCaseArgumentsType) {
    this.arguments = value;
  }
  private arguments!: TestCaseArgumentsType;
  sampleTestFunction() {
    console.log('===execute 2===');
    console.log(this.arguments.url); // another sampleUrl

    it('to check the before each execution effects in the test case', () => {
      console.log('===execute 4===');
      console.log(this.arguments.url); // sampleUrl
    });
  }
}
```

`sampleTestSuite.test.ts`:

```js
import { Sample, TestCaseArgumentsType } from './sampleTest';

describe('User Route', () => {
  let sample = new Sample();
  describe('GET Request', () => {
    console.log('===execute 1===');
    sample.args = <TestCaseArgumentsType>{ url: `another sampleUrl` };
    beforeAll(async () => {
      console.log('===execute 3===');
      sample.args = <TestCaseArgumentsType>{ url: `sampleUrl` };
    }, 20000);
    sample.sampleTestFunction();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58480169/sampleTestSuite.test.ts (7.092s)
  User Route
    GET Request
      ✓ to check the before each execution effects in the test case (3ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58480169/sampleTestSuite.test.ts:8
    ===execute 1===

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58480169/sampleTest.ts:11
    ===execute 2===

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58480169/sampleTest.ts:12
    another sampleUrl

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58480169/sampleTestSuite.test.ts:11
    ===execute 3===

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58480169/sampleTest.ts:15
    ===execute 4===

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58480169/sampleTest.ts:16
    sampleUrl

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.89s
```

As you can see, I put some `console.log` to indicate the execution order of the code. The execution order is `1,2,3,4`. Sorry for my English.

Comment: is it possible to get the value without initializing two times(inside describe and inside beforeAll).